# Storage/database solution for a custom POP3 Client?

Tags: linux, qt, storage

The POP3 client is an homework assignment at one of my courses. It has to be done in Qt from scratch. Target platform: Linux (Ubuntu).

What solution would you recommend when it comes to mail storage ? Since it is a homework assignment it has to be done "right"...

P.S. For now I think I would go with plain text, each message in a separate .txt and another file as an index. I'm not sure how this will be handled when the folder with the messages will get really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my options where totally open, I'd pick a database tool ([MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) is overkill,  [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) would be perfect) because the tool can deal with sorting, IO access, file locks (if multiple instances are possible), deleting, defragmenting/cleaning/vacuuming.

On the other hand... there's a pair of standards for storing mail: MBOX and maildir ([nice primer here](http://www.linuxmail.info/mbox-maildir-mail-storage-formats/)) which it wouldn't be too hard to adopt into your programme.

What of attachments, text encoding and transfer encoding?  That's where the real work's going to lie (unless it's out of scope of the assignment).

Comment: Thanks, maildir would be perfect :). Yeah, I think my client should be able to get attachments, but that's the mime parser's problem, not storage.. about the encoding teacher didn't say anything, so.. it's not my problem :)